# SSH Selenium Session Crashes on Logout (even with "screen", "nohup" etc)

Tags: selenium, ssh, automated-tests, geckodriver, mobaxterm

I'm running a Selenium webscraper in Java on a Linux server through SSH, but the browser crashes upon termination of the session despite various attempts to instruct the program to run in the background. Specifically, I've used `screen`, `tmux`, `nohup`, `disown`, and `setsid` (as here https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/) with similar, bad results. I would like to try a VNC session, but so far not enabled on the server.

With `screen` for example:

1. I type `screen`, run the program, and normal output is produced
2. I detach the screen with `Ctrl+a+d`, normal output continues to be produced
3. I end the SSH session. Output ceases and (upon logging back in and returning to the screen session), I get the error message

```
Exiting due to channel error
Exiting due to channel error
Exiting due to channel error
Exiting due to channel error
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

I've tried this a couple of times, so it's not a coincidence that it crashes at the exact time of ending the SSH session. What could be going wrong and how can I try to diagnose the issue?

System information:

```
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Linux 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
Java: 1.8.0_252
Firefox version: Mozilla Firefox 78.3.1esr
Firefox boot options: "--marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile"
Gecko driver version: 0.27.0
Selenium version: 3.141.59m revision e82be7d358
SSH client: MobaXTerm, personal version 10.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through sheer dumb trial and error luck I tried swapping MobaXTerm for PuTTY (continuing to use `screen`) and the problem went away. I have no idea why this works. The universe is a complex place which surpasses mere human comprehension.

Comment: My admin's thoughts: 

"I'm wondering if the default ssh settings for a new session in putty being slightly different than Mobaxterm's might have helped. One of those differences, Mobaxterm by default creates two sessions to the host, an ssh terminal & an sftp browser.
I have seen this cause problems in the past in some situations and changing the "SSH-Browser type" in the "Advanced SSH Settings" tab to "None" resolves the issue.
2. "X11-Forwarding". By default in putty it is off, in Mobaxterm it is on.
3. "Compression". By default in putty it is off, in Mobaxterm it is on."